# Unable to parse HTML by BeautifulSoup / LXML

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have an HTML page and I want to find some items of it.
I am finding it hard to apply beautifulsoup or lxml

HTML page:

```
<li class="context-card">
    <div class="episode" data-id="t1">
        <span class="av-play">Title to scrape</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="context-card">
    <div class="episode" data-id="t2">
        <span class="av-play">Title2 to scrape</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="context-card">
    <div class="episode" data-id="t3">
        <span class="av-play">Title3 to scrape</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

How to get all these 3 Ids and titles in a different dictionary within a list

```
[{'id':'t1', 'title': 'Title to scrape'}, {'id':'t2', 'title': 'Title2 to scrape'}, {'id':'t3', 'title': 'Title3 to scrape'}]
```

Comment: *"I am finding it hard to apply beautifulshoup or lxml"* then you can probably share your current Python code which almost works but has a specific error message?

Comment: @Tomalak, actually text is much bigger and i just make a format. don't have any idea on how exactly to apply lxml or beautifulsoup. I searched on the web but it could not help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the titles and IDs you need are located inside the `<span>` tag with the `class="episode"` attribute. So, your job is to iterate over all of those tags and get the `'data-id'` of the `div` tag and the `text` of its inner `span` tag.

Code:

```
html = '''
<li class="context-card">
    <div class="episode" data-id="t1">
        <span class="av-play">Title to scrape</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="context-card">
    <div class="episode" data-id="t2">
        <span class="av-play">Title2 to scrape</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="context-card">
    <div class="episode" data-id="t3">
        <span class="av-play">Title3 to scrape</span>
    </div>
</li>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

title_list = []
for ep in soup.find_all('div', class_='episode'):
    curr_dict = {'id': ep['data-id'], 'title': ep.span.text}
    title_list.append(curr_dict)

print(title_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 't1', 'title': 'Title to scrape'},
 {'id': 't2', 'title': 'Title2 to scrape'},
 {'id': 't3', 'title': 'Title3 to scrape'}]
```

Or, the same can be done using a list comprehension:

```
title_list = [{'id': ep['data-id'], 'title': ep.span.text} for ep in soup.find_all('div', class_='episode')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what if I need the value of div attribute as an 'id' so the output will look like [{'title': text, 'id': num}, {}] like this

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you want exactly. Can you add this with an example in the question itself? I'll edit my answer accordingly.